# How to specify the file type that an executable accepts as arguments from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments

When I type acroread and first couple of letters of the PDF I want to open and hit [Tab] it autocompletes the file name with the .pdf file. Even if there are other matching file names with the same starting letters as the ones i typed in but with different extensions like .ps. My C++ code accepts text file names with a custom extension .tk3 as input argument. how do I setup my code to do the same thing acroread does?

Comment: It's not your code you have to set up, it's your shell's completion routines.

Comment: That's something that your shell does. You don't have any influence on this behavior with your program. I'd guess there's some information available for the shell, which program will deal with particular file extensions associated.

Comment: That sounds like the programmable completion built into your shell. You can configure the shell to do what you want, but it's not a function of your code/program.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that. I use Suse Linux 11 at work and dont have too many permissions to adjust stuff. hope i can set this up. Thank for your help.